# Using the open sets definition of continuity to show that $f : S^2 → R^2$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have to show that a specific given function $f : S^2 → R^2$ such that $(x, y, z) \mapsto (a, b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are two compositions of continuous functions in $x$, $y$ and $z$ that are also given, is continuous.  I know I have to show that the preimage in $S^2$ of any open subsets of $R^2$ is open. My $a$ is such that $(x, y, z) \neq$ $(0, 0, 0)$, or it would be undefined, and my $b$ is such that $(x, y, z) \neq(1, 1, 1)$, or it would be undefined, but since $S^2 =\{(x, y, z)  |  x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\}$, I can see that this would not be an issue.  Other than referencing the fact that the composition of continuous functions is continuous, is there a standard way to approach a question like this?  I have seen examples where we map from $R^3$ to $R$, but nothing like this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is far too vague to be answered. Why don't you write down $f$?

Comment: If I understand well, $a$ and $b$ are the restrictions of functions defined on $\mathbb R^3$ (or some open subset of it) to $S^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ and $b$ are defined using coordinates, we can define $F=(a,b)$ as an application from a subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^3$ into $\mathbb R^2$ and the question is to show that its restriction $f=F_{|S}$ from $S=S^2$ into $\mathbb R^2$ is continuous.

Since $a$ and $b$ are composition of continuous functions, they are continuous (as applications from $U$ into $\mathbb R$). Therefore, since $\mathbb R^2$ has the product topology, $F=(a,b)$ is continuous.

Now, since the topology of $S$ is the topology induced on $S$ by the topology of $\mathbb R^3$, the restriction $f=F_{|S}$ is continuous.

Comment: Note: I think Jason's answer is great, but I tried to add an answer using only vocabulary about topological spaces, as requested in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity is closed under composition, so $a, b$ are continuous. Cartesian product of continuous functions is continuous if the space is equipped with a conserving metric, and the Euclidean distance is in fact conserving. So this function is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I should have mentioned that I'm not considering metric spaces, just topological spaces.

Comment: That is a nonsense distinction: you're working in Euclidean spaces so metric **and** topological arguments apply (we use whatever is more convenient) @user604270

Comment: What I meant to say is that I have not yet covered metric spaces, only general topological spaces, so a space being equipped with a conserving metric does not yet mean anything to me.

Comment: What topologies are your spaces equipped with?

Answer (score 0):

In my mind the easiest way to show that a function is continuous is by showing that it is given by composing continuous functions or that it is obtained from universal properties.

In this specific instance note that the universal property of the product states that to give a continuous map into $\Bbb R^n$ amounts to giving $n$ (possibly distinct) maps into $\Bbb R$. Hence it suffices to show that the maps $a: \Bbb S^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and $b: \Bbb S^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ are continuous. Let me discuss the first one, the second is completely analogous.

Let $i: \Bbb S^2 \subseteq \Bbb R^3$ denote the inclusion of the sphere into the ambient space. The function $v:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3, (x,y,z) \mapsto (\vert x \vert,\vert y\vert, \vert z \vert)$ is continuous by the universal property of $\Bbb R^3$ and the fact that $\vert-\vert: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous. The function $p:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R, (x,y,z) \mapsto x+y+z$ is continous. We obtain $a$ as the composite $p\circ v \circ i$, hence it is continous.